# Recursive binary search implementation is crashing... why?

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, binary-search

I'm trying to find and fix what is wrong with this code. It's a binary search implemented by recursion. I dont know why it's returning stack overflow and crashing.

```
bool find( const int x, const int* pBegin, const int* pEnd)
{
    int medel = (*pBegin +(( *pEnd-1) - *pBegin)/2) ;

    if(x == medel)
        return true ;

    else if( x > medel) 
    {
        int begin = (medel +1);

        return find (x, &begin, pEnd);
    }
    else if( x< medel)
    {
        int last = (medel-1);

        return find(x,pBegin, &last);
    }

}


void main()
{
    int arr[10];
    for (int i=0;i<10;++i)
        arr[i] = i;
    bool hittat = find(7, &arr[0], &arr[9]);
    cout << "hittat = " << hittat << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

When I debug the code, I see that when the function "find" is called it takes weird arguments, like in [this pic](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/580/capturepzr.jpg/).

It should take 0 and 9, not these huge numbers :/
Is there anything wrong with my pointers?

Comment: As much as I agree with the answer given so far, suggesting to compute the average of pointers rather than the average of values, I do not think that this is at the root of your problem: your code is only testing values, never pointers, so it should run without troubles. In fact, it is as if it was passing values instead of pointers and determine if the first argument is between the second and the third. Which is likely *not* what you want, but should not be the root cause of your problem. I tried it on my system and I do not observe that behavior. Aren't you debugging a release build?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `medel` (I'm assuming that should be `middle`) as a pointer to an `int` in some places, but as an `int` in others.

Try declaring it like this:

```
const int* middle = pBegin + (pEnd - pBegin + 1) / 2;
```

Then, when you want to access what is stored there, use `*medel`.

Also, you'll need a second terminating condition (for when it won't be found). Something like:

```
if (((middle == pEnd) && (x > *middle)) ||
         ((middle == pBegin) && (x < *middle))) {
  // Terminating condition                                                                                                                                                                              
  return false;
}
```

Comment: The `-sizeof(int)` part does not belong here. Arithmetic with typed pointers increments already takes size into account under the hood. And only some variants of the algorithm would have a -1 here.

Answer (score 1):

You should compute the average of the **pointers** and check what it's the **value** of the element hallway between them. Instead you compute the average of the **values** pointed by them which is significantly different.

Comment: could you please describe more

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing pointer on int and int with your medel, just set it to be a pointer and access his data with `*medel`

Answer (score 0):

The problem shown in your picture looks like it was taken from your original code as seen in a  prior question. There you had pEnd pointing past the end of an array, so that dereferencing it was not allowed (and yields weird values).

That should not occur with the code as posted.

Your current code only uses pointers to valid integers. But most of those don't point into your array, so what you do is not a search in your array. The program simply does calculations with integers. Only the values of the first and last element of your array are ever used.

The program is confusing, because you pass around the integer values as pointers to their storage. While you start with pointers into your array, you then mix in pointers to automatic variables (`begin`and `end`), where you have stored a calculated value. (You never use pointers to array elements other than the first and last.